# How to Initiate Outbound Messages from Bot to Skype for Business When users are offline

Tags: c#, botframework, skype-for-business

According to [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview#create-outbound-bots) and [two](https://www.raydbg.com/2018/How-to-initiate-outbound-messages-from-Skype-for-Business-bots-to-users/), I find it's possible to send a proactive message to users. But it seems it doesn't work when users are offline. Is it possible?

I'm using C# and bot framework V3.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to send a message to users even when users are not online
2. If I use the code as below which is from two,  is it possible to start a dialog? If yes, how?

my code is as below

```
public class CustomWebAPIController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]

    [Route("api/CustomWebAPI")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendMessage([FromBody]string userobj)
    {
        try
        {

            //Initiate a Conversation
            string trustServiceUri = "https://api.skypeforbusiness.com/platformservice/botframework";
            MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(trustServiceUri);
            ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(trustServiceUri));
            List<ChannelAccount> participants = new List<ChannelAccount>();
            participants.Add(new ChannelAccount("sip:XXXXX@XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com", "Agent"));
            ConversationParameters parameters = new ConversationParameters(true, new ChannelAccount("sip:XXXXXbot@XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com", "Bot"), participants, "TestTopic");
            ConversationResourceResponse response = connector.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(parameters).Result;

            //Initiate another connector with the ServiceURL from above response.
            ConnectorClient connectorSend = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(response.ServiceUrl));
            IMessageActivity msg = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
            msg.Recipient = new ChannelAccount("sip:XXXXX@XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com", "Agent");
            msg.Text = "text message";
            msg.Locale = "en-Us";
            msg.From = new ChannelAccount("sip:XXXXXbot@XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com", "Bot");
            msg.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
            msg.Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
            msg.ChannelId = "skypeforbusiness";
            msg.ServiceUrl = response.ServiceUrl;
            msg.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(isGroup: true, id: response.Id, name: null);
            //Send the message from Bot to User
            //var result = connectorSend.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(msg.Conversation.Id, (Activity)msg).Result;
            await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)msg);

            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            return resp;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "But it seems it doesn't work when users are offline": source?

Comment: I have updated my code. can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

The first doc you referenced states:

> as long as the user is in a user-initiated conversation with the bot
>   and still has the Skype conversation window open

This is currently a limitation of Skype for Business Bots (preview).

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of it. According to the second doc. I succeed in sending a proactive message to users even when a user doesn't have skype conversation open. But fail when the user is offline(the user hasn't open Skype for business).